# Code pushed webhook in AzureDevops is pre-push hook or post push hook?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-hooks

I would like to know if the "code pushed" webhook in AzureDevops is before code is pushed to the repository or after code is pushed to the repository?

In case the configured webhook is not reachable or throws some exception, is it possible to not push the code?

Comment: How would a hook that runs on the server be able to run **before** you push code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webhook is triggered after code pushed. It seems unachievable from azure devops side not to push code. You may need to manually check the webhook connection and decide whether to push your code.